# Duplicating row when pasting

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, copy, pasting

I have a vba code that is supposed to copy any row on a sheet called "Projects Overview" with "Complete - Design" in the "N" column and paste it to the another sheet. This was working correctly for awhile, but now it pastes the row more than once. I found that the number of duplicates pasted matches the number of rows being used in the "Projects Overview" sheet. I think that the code is just looping and running through each row.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub CompleteJob()

'Looks through the status column (N) of the Projects Overview table and moves them to Completed table, then deletes row from projects list
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LrowProjectsOverview As Long

With Sheets("Projects Overview")
    .Select

    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    For LrowProjectsOverview = lastRow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(LrowProjectsOverview, "N")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If ((.Value = "Complete - Design") Or (.Value = "P4P") Or (.Value = "Ready for Setup")) Then .EntireRow.Copy Sheet3.Range("A200")

                    If Sheet9.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
                        Sheet9.Range("A2:Q2").Value = Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Value
                        Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").ClearContents

                        Else

                        Sheet9.Range("B2").EntireRow.Insert
                        Sheet9.Range("A2:Q2").Value = Sheet3.Range("A200:Q200").Value
                        Sheet3.Range("A16:Q16").ClearContents
                        Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Interior.Color = xlNone
                        Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Font.Bold = False
                        Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").Font.Color = vbBlack
                        Sheet9.Range("B2:Q2").RowHeight = 14.25

                    End If

                    If Sheet9.Range("B2").Value = "" Then
                       Sheet9.Range("B2").EntireRow.Delete

                    End If

                If ((.Value = "Complete - Design") Or (.Value = "P4P") Or (.Value = "Ready for Setup")) Then .EntireRow.Delete

            End If
        End With
    Next LrowProjectsOverview
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: have you actually debugged the code line-by-line to see where it's not behaving as expected?

Comment: Yes, I can see that it is getting stuck in a loop somehow. It should be looking through "N" for the specific phrases and only copying that entire row, but it is looking through "N", finding the phrase, and making multiple copies in the new sheet. It looks like it makes a copy of the correct row, loops back to the top of the script, and makes a copy of that row everytime there is anything written in a row on that sheet.

Comment: If you step through the code *line-by-line* and compare its actions against what is expected you will see exactly where the code is malfunctioning. Without any sample data its very hard to help you here, as in general, the code looks good.